# ringojs fileupload example

Tags: file-upload, serverside-javascript, ringojs

Does anyone have an example of uploading a file to the server using ringojs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simple [upload example](http://github.com/ringo/ringojs/blob/master/apps/demo/actions.js#L20-31) in the demo app, but it stores uploads in-memory which is not a good idea for most apps. To save uploads to a temporary file you'll currently have to do something like this (this is a modified version of the upload demo action):

```
var fu = require("ringo/webapp/fileupload");

function upload(req) {
    if (fu.isFileUpload(req.contentType)) {
        var params = {};
        fu.parseFileUpload(req, params, req.charset, fu.TempFileFactory);
        return {
            status: 200,
            headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
            body: [params.file.name, " saved to ", params.file.tempfile]
        };
    }
    return Response.skin(module.resolve('skins/upload.txt'), {
        title: "File Upload"
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, there was a bug with saving uploads to temp files that I just fixed, so you'll have to use a current git snapshot or patch file `modules/ringo/webapp/fileupload.js` manually:

`http://github.com/ringo/ringojs/commit/1793a815a9ca3ffde4aa5a07c656456969b504f9`

We also need some high level way of doing this for the next release (e.g. setting a `req.uploadTempDir` property). I'll open an issue for this.